# Using joinRelated for multiple relation filtering

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

I have a `collection`, a `product` and a `collection_product` join table. If I'm trying to filter products based on collection ids, I do the following:

```
Product.query()
  .modify((builder) => {
    if (collectionIds?.length) {   
      builder 
        .joinRelated({ collections: true })
        .whereIn('collections.id', collectionIds)
        .groupBy('product.id');  
    }
  }
```

Now we added *child products* into our `product` table that are the same as regular products, except they contain the parent id in the `parent_product_id` column.

These child products are not part of the `collection_product` table, so the above modifier will only return parent products. Is there a way to also include child products into the results if there's a match on the parent product?

I tried joining both `collections` and `parentProduct.collections`, but it didn't work. They only work separately. So by doing this:

```
.joinRelated({ parentProduct: { collections: true } })
.whereIn('parentProduct:collections.id', collectionIds)
```

I was able to get all the child products that have parents that belong to a collection, but not the parent products. How can I get both?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `.withGraphJoined({ parentProduct: { collections: true } })`

https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/eager-methods.html#withgraphjoined

instead of `.joinRelated`. It should also include joined relation to the results.